# To what extent are prompters needed in, say, Metropolitan Opera productions?

Tags: memorization, opera

Of course, prompters are meant to be unseen. And in the current Metropolitan Opera daily streamings, say, they don't seem to play any evident role. Are they, in fact, (often) needed?

What qualifies one to be a prompter? I guess there are different ones for, at least, operas in different languages.

Are the prompters listed among the lengthy credits that roll at the end? It would be of interest to know their identities and whether they have individual standing as musicians/singers.

Are their famous episodes (perhaps available on-line) in which prompters were clearly needed?

In a sense, this question is motivated by the impressive command/memorizations that singers seem to have of their libretti. But how perfect is this--and, in any case, are any lapses by-and-large hidden from the viewing public?

Comment: What is your question?  Are you assuming you can *see* the prompter but don't recognize any cues he's providing?   I will state that the choice of language is irrelevant here.

Comment: I have put this on hold for the moment as there doesn't appear to be a clear on topic question. Please read our [ask] and [about] pages, and see if you can edit to clearly articulate an on-topic question

Comment: "I guess there are different ones for, at least, operas in different languages": why?  There same singers sing in multiple languages.  There's no reason why prompters can't handle multiple languages as well.

Comment: Prompters are singers and they are used in every production at the met. They have to be able to read music and follow the score. There is a small box down center stage at the Met’s opera house that is hard to see and often covered by scenery (from the audience side). That is where the prompter is. Of course anyone on stage at the Met is a performer of the highest caliber, and a prompter is just added insurance. “The prompter has to be a highly trained musician” https://www.ny1.com/nyc/all-boroughs/news/2019/05/06/an-on-stage-look-into-the-work-of-an-opera-prompter

Comment: There are two valid questions here: are prompters needed, and what are their qualifications? There's also a good answer as a comment, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: According to my dictionary a prompter could also be simply device with a screen showing the text, so I would prefer to have the *person* appearing early in the question or the French *souffleur*, which seems the basis used for quite a few languages.

Comment: @guidot The French 'Souffleur/-euse' is also used in German, but in English the term 'prompter' is more usual, and if it's a device: 'teleprompter'.